# The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jackson

Here I am using Jackson data binder 2.4.1 jar library in my eclipse project to convert an object to a json format. And here is my code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
mapper.writeValue(wr, content);
```

but in the last line `mapper.writeValue(wr, content);` it gives an error saying

```
The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have studied and found that when a jar file's class is dependent on another class which is unavailable then this type of error occurs. But from where I am using this code snippet there is no issue like this. But I have failed a lot of time by changing the JAR version but nothing solved this issue. How can I solve this, please help

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need both `jackson-databind` and `jackson-core` on your classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Add **jackson-core** to your classpath in addition to jackson-databind.

Steps :

1. Download jackson-core JAR file from [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki#download)
2. Right click on the project and go to properties > Build path > Libraries > classpath
3. Select 'Add external JARs'
4. Choose the file location
5. Click on 'Apply and close'.