# Adding a .jar file to classpath through maven

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm having some trouble in getting maven to download a number of .jar files my application depends on. The code in which these dependencies are needed is bellow:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServerConfiguration {
    public String info = null;
    public String idlURL = null;
    public String idlContents = null;
    public List<ServerInfo> servers = new ArrayList<>();

    public final void clear() {
        info = null;
        idlURL = null;
        idlContents = null;
        if (servers != null)
            servers.clear();
    }

    private final static ObjectReader jsonReader;
    private final static ObjectWriter jsonWriter;

    static {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true); // <== Error:(52, 15) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator not found
        //mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, true);
        jsonWriter = mapper.writer();
        jsonReader = mapper.reader(ServerConfiguration.class);
    }

    public static ServerConfiguration fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
        return jsonReader.<ServerConfiguration>readValue(json); // <== Error:(59, 26) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException not found
    }

    public String toJson() throws IOException {
        return jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(this);
    }

}
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413842/the-type-com-fasterxml-jackson-core-jsongenerator-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indi) question, I tried adding the mentioned packages(**jackson-databind**, **jackson-core**) to **pom.xml**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How can I add the respective dependencies?

**Edit #1:**

The errors given are bellow(the lines where they occur are marked in the code above):

```
Error:(52, 15) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
  class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator not found
Error:(54, 28) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec
  class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec not found
Error:(55, 28) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Base64Variant
  class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Base64Variant not found
Error:(59, 26) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
  class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException not found
Error:(63, 26) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned
  class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned not found
```

**Edit #2:**

I can't seem to add the dependencies:

[image: dependencies]

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with `2.5.4` version as below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

In IntelliJ, try to tick a `checkbox` "export" in your `dependencies`.

I mean: Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies, and there you can see libs included to the module. You should also see a `checkbox` near each lib in column 'Export'.

Comment: Did you compiled your code after adding dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I've compiled it with all dependency variations.

Comment: Updated the answer, can you try with that?

Comment: I've tried adding the dependencies but get the error mentioned in the updated question.

Comment: Can you try building your project from outside Intellij?

Comment: No, how should I go about that?

Comment: From command line got to project directly parallel to `pom.xml` and execute command `mvn clean install`

Comment: Strangely, it compiles. How can I change the maven version intellij is using?

Comment: Then, it's the problem with intellij, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199711/class-file-not-found-in-intellij

Comment: I've already tried adding them via the project but get the error mentioned in the second edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For databind you want this:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

What is missing?  Can you post an error message or stack trace?

[Here is a good site to find dependencies for maven.](http://mvnrepository.com/)

Comment: Yes, I've edited the source. I already have that entry in pom.xml.

Comment: Again, can you post an error message or stack trace to show the problem?