# Jackson cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, jackson

This question is a follow up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318636/adding-a-jar-file-to-classpath-through-maven). I can't seem to be able to access the jackson library in the following code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServerConfiguration {
    public String info = null;
    public String idlURL = null;
    public String idlContents = null;
    public List<ServerInfo> servers = new ArrayList<>();

    public final void clear() {
        info = null;
        idlURL = null;
        idlContents = null;
        if (servers != null)
            servers.clear();
    }

    private final static ObjectReader jsonReader;
    private final static ObjectWriter jsonWriter;

    static {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true); // <== Error:(52, 15) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator not found
        //mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, true);
        jsonWriter = mapper.writer();
        jsonReader = mapper.reader(ServerConfiguration.class);
    }

    public static ServerConfiguration fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
        return jsonReader.<ServerConfiguration>readValue(json); // <== Error:(59, 26) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException not found
    }

    public String toJson() throws IOException {
        return jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(this);
    }

}
```

eventhough the jar files are in the classpath(autocomplete shows the method declaration in Intellij).

What am I missing?

Comment: In my case the reason was that I had two different versions of Jackson libraries in the classpath.

Answer (score 41):

When I had this problem I had the **jackson-annotations** and **jackson-databind** jars in my classpath, but not **jackson-core**.

Adding jackson-core to the classpath solved it for me.

Comment: If you're using Maven, also make sure that you use the correct `<scope></scope>` value. This tells maven when and in some cases how it should resolve dependencies. Available values are `compile`, `provided`, `runtime`, `test`, `system` and `import`, you can read more about what they do here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29230903/2804473

Comment: Adding this to the pom.xml fixed for me. Thanks for sharing your finding, this is based on that.:


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

Answer (score 16):

I was having a similar issue, it turned out to be an IntelliJ issue.

This helped me to resolve the issue:

Try `File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and Restart`.

If it doesn't help, delete `.idea` directory and reimport from pom/gradle build file.

Answer (score 5):

Also double check that all your Jackson dependencies use the same version like below :

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.1'
```

I previously had `jackson-core:2.11.0` and this was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this kind of error: `Cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode`

My first version of the maven POM contained:

- `jackson-annotations`
- `jackson-databind`

It was working fine until I wanted to add `jackson-core` for unit tests. I added it with the `test` scope and the error appeared. After some investigation, I found out that to make it working, I had to remove the `test` scope, otherwise this error appears. If someone has an explanation I would be interested :)

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered the same problem, turns out, I had "jackson-core-asl.jar" instead of "jackson-core.jar"

So, check whether you have this jar-file in your classpath.
-> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Answer (score 0):

1 go to the .m2/repository and delete the conflicting files

2 `mvn -U clean install`