# Issue on json parsing

Tags: java

```
String jsonMessage = mapper.writeValueAsString(m);
```

The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.`JSonprocessingException` cannot be resolved it is indirectly referenced by a .class.

I tried to update it with pom of jackson

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>


 // avoid too much magic and transform ourselves
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
 //mapper.writeValueAsString(m);
  String jsonMessage =mapper.writeValueAsString(m.toString());
```

Actual it must not show error on line

Comment: Can u please provide the error stacktrace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413842/the-type-com-fasterxml-jackson-core-jsongenerator-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indi)

Comment: The version of Jackson you're using is very old, you may want to consider updating to a newer version.

Comment: Can you please suggest which version I have to use.